# How to browse object hierarchy in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I went to an interview recently and there they asked me the following question:

Write a component to travel through an object hierarchy based on the data path passed in and return the value of the property implemeting the following method:

Public object getValueFromPath(object parentObj, string dataPath);

The object hierarchy will be some thing like this:

```
Object1
  objectRef2
    property1
    property2
```

parentObj will be Object1

dataPath will be objectRef2.property2

Can some one give me an idea how I can do that.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a very clear interview question.

Comment: @scott, seems clear enough to me.  It's trying to guage the interviewee's familiarity with reflection.  This is about as canonical and trivial a reflection question you could ask, so it seems fair to me.

Comment: @Kirk now that the question has been edited, I get it :)

Comment: Maybe it was a 'trick' question.  And the correct answer is "the requirements are confusing, could you clarify then?"

Comment: Any ideas or short code snippet that I can use to implement this?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp), along with Andrew's answer, might get you close to answering your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to use reflection.

First step would be to split the `dataPath` on `.`, and get a reference to the `System.Type` object representing the type of `parentObj`  (`parentObj.GetType()`).

Then for each element in the path you would use something like `.GetMember(...)` on the `Type` object to find the member with that name, and update the current `Type` object accordingly.

Once you get to the property at the end, and you have the associated `ProprtyInfo` object, you then need to call `.GetValue(...)` to get the value of the property.

Comment: Thanks @@Andrew. I am very new to reflection. Can you please give a short code snippet that I can work it on?

Comment: @HRK, he could, but you would be far better served just reading up on the API docs ([System.Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx), [Type.GetProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy.aspx), etc.).  It's not a very difficult API, and it's clear you haven't exercised it much, so it's time for you to play with the API and figure out how it works.

Comment: Sure then. I'll try to figure it out and will get back if I had any issues.